# How to clear values of dropdownlists in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am using ng-repeat in HTML to loop on a javascript array. showing this array in select.
what i want to do is to clear all selected data from these dropdownlists when press on a button

HTML

```
<div class="widget-title">
                                <div class="widget-controls">
                                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="newassignment()">New</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" ng-click="saveavd()">Save</button>
                                </div>
                                <h3><i class="icon-ok-sign"></i>Assignment</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div id="vacation" class="widget-content" style="height:81vh; overflow:auto;">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <table style="width: 70%;" border="1">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Departments</th>
                                                <th>Work Level</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr ng-repeat="d in departments | filter : depts">
                                                <td>
                                                    <input style=" margin-top: 0;" type="checkbox"  ng-model="d.details"/> {{d.Dep_LDesc}}
                                                </td>

                                                <td>
                                                    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="wrklevel2">
                                                        <option ng-repeat="w in worklevel" value="{{w.lvlid}}">{{w.lvlnm}}</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

angularjs

```
 $scope.worklevel = [
        { lvlid: 1, lvlnm: 'First Level' },
        { lvlid: 2, lvlnm: 'Second Level' }
    ]

$scope.newassignment = function () {


            $scope.wrklevel2 = {};


        angular.forEach($scope.departments, function (d) {
            d.details = false;
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have different models for your selects inside your ng-repeat to achieve that you can try the following

(**ng-model="d.wrklevel2"**)

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="d.wrklevel2">
    <option ng-repeat="w in worklevel" value="{{w.lvlid}}">{{w.lvlnm}}</option>
</select>
```

after that you can also clear values of select inside your forEach loop

```
angular.forEach($scope.departments, function (d) {
    d.details = false;
    d.wrklevel2 = undefined;
})
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

set the ngModel of `select` to empty string -

```
function saveavd()
{
  $scope.wrklevel2 = ""
  // ...
}
```

Comment: i did it but still not working, and i added $scope.$apply(); , but still not working

Comment: Your controller name in `<input style=" margin-top: 0;" type="checkbox"  ng-model="d.details"/>` is different and ngmodel name for `<select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="wrklevel2">` is different. The solution suggested by NTP is correct.

Comment: Thanks you very much